# List of commands in Node.js

Tags: node.js

This may be a rather stupid question to ask, but is there a specific command I can use from inside Node.js in order to list it's built-in commands?  I was attempting to find the command to back out of Node.js and into the command prompt, but I also wished to view the other basic commands and their functions.

Comment: More than anything at the moment, I'm attempting to find what I need to input in order to return to the command prompt instead of the Node console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or the `.exit` command to exit the Node.js REPL interpreter.

There are a few other commands available at the REPL prompt that are documented [here](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features). You can also use the `.help` command to show them.